# algorithm - node - tree - typescript

Tags: typescript, algorithm, tree

I have a json in raw data unsorted like this :

```
[
  {
    "level": 1,
    "id": 34,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 10
  },
  {
    "level": 3,
    "id": 48521,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 684
  },
  {
    "level": 5,
    "id": 12138,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 213
  },
  
  {
    "level": 4,
    "id": 5679,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 12138
  },
  {
    "level": 5,
    "id": 4789,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 10769
  },
  {
    "level": 3,
    "id": 998797988,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 5679
  },
  {
    "level": 3,
    "id": 987987777,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 5679
  },
  {
    "level": 4,
    "id": 4417,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 4789
  },
  {
    "level": 3,
    "id": 12138,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 4417
  },
  {
    "level": 4,
    "id": 5678,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 12138
  },
  {
    "level": 3,
    "id": 998797987,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 5678
  },
  {
    "level": 5,
    "id": 326,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 20
  },
  {
    "level": 4,
    "id": 684,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 326
  },
  {
    "level": 2,
    "id": 54444,
    "name": "example-name",
    "father_id": 26580
  }
]
```

My ultimate goal would be to be able to have this result :

```
[
  {
    "parent": {
      "level": 5,
      "id": 12138,
      "name": "example-name",
      "father_id": 213
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "level": 3,
        "id": 998797987,
        "name": "example-name",
        "father_id": 5678
      },
      {
        "level": 3,
        "id": 998797988,
        "name": "example-name",
        "father_id": 5679
      },
      {
        "level": 3,
        "id": 987987777,
        "name": "example-name",
        "father_id": 5679
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent": {
      "level": 5,
      "id": 326,
      "name": "example-name",
      "father_id": 20
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "level": 3,
        "id": 48521,
        "name": "example-name",
        "father_id": 684
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent" : {
      "level": 5,
      "id": 4789,
      "name": "example-name",
      "father_id": 10769
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "level": 3,
        "id": 12138,
        "name": "example-name",
        "father_id": 4417
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

To let you understand how it works, I created this intermediate json :

```
[
  {
    "parent": {
      "level": 5,
      "id": 12138,
      "name": "example-name",
      "father_id": 213
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "parent": {
          "level": 4,
          "id": 5678,
          "name": "example-name",
          "father_id": 12138
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": 998797987,
            "name": "example-name",
            "father_id": 5678
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "parent": {
          "level": 4,
          "id": 5679,
          "name": "example-name",
          "father_id": 12138
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": 998797988,
            "name": "example-name",
            "father_id": 5679
          },
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": 987987777,
            "name": "example-name",
            "father_id": 5679
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent": {
      "level": 5,
      "id": 326,
      "name": "example-name",
      "father_id": 20
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "parent": {
          "level": 4,
          "id": 684,
          "name": "example-name",
          "father_id": 326
        },
        "children": [{
          "level": 3,
          "id": 48521,
          "name": "example-name",
          "father_id": 684
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent" : {
      "level": 5,
      "id": 4789,
      "name": "example-name",
      "father_id": 10769
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "parent": {
          "level": 4,
          "id": 4417,
          "name": "example-name",
          "father_id": 4789
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": 12138,
            "name": "example-name",
            "father_id": 4417
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In the previous json each `father_id` is linked to the `id` of his parent.

I have in my json different `level` (6 to 1). I'm interested in having the relation between `level 5` and `level 3`.

Here is what I did in typescript :

```js
    const families: { parent: Treeview; children: Treeview[] }[] = []

    arrayTreeViews.forEach(node => {
      // keep level between 3 to 5
      if ( node.level < 3 || node.level > 5 ) return
      // get root parent
      if ( node.level === 4 ) families.push({parent: node, children: []})

      // issue with the following line is :
      // as the array is not sorted the node itself might not has any parent yet...
      const parentIndex = families.findIndex(el => el.parent.id === node.fatherId)
      if ( parentIndex !== -1 ) {
        families[parentIndex].children.push(node)
        return
      }
    })
```

How could I achieve the expected json result the most efficent way possible in typescript ?

I thought about sorting first the array on the property level but I don't know how could I get directly the relation between `level 5` to `level 3`

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT :**

Message deleted because it was the wrong solution :/

**EDIT 2 :**
Solution found : so same question as earlier ? Is it the best way / most efficient way to do it ? Thanks for your help /  advice

```
    const rootLevel: { parent: Treeview; children: Treeview[] }[] = []
    const subLevel: Treeview[] = []
    const lowerLevel: Treeview[] = []

    arrayTreeViews.forEach(node => {
      if ( node.level === 4 ) rootLevel.push({parent: node, children: []})
      if ( node.level === 3 ) subLevel.push(node)
      if ( node.level === 2 ) lowerLevel.push(node)
    })

    subLevel.forEach(node => {
      const parentIndex = rootLevel.findIndex(el => el.parent.id === node.fatherId)
      const familyTreeView = lowerLevel.filter(el => el.fatherId === node.id)
      if ( familyTreeView && parentIndex !== -1) {
        rootLevel[parentIndex].children.push(...familyTreeView)
      }
    })
    res.json(rootLevel)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:** Since the question has changed, I had to write a new answer*

```js
const findChildren = (tree: Treeview[], node: Treeview) =>
  tree.filter(
    (treeNode) =>
      treeNode.level === node.level - 1 && treeNode.father_id === node.id
  );

const findGrandchildren = (tree: Treeview[], node: Treeview) =>
  findChildren(tree, node).flatMap((child) => findChildren(tree, child));

const families = arrayTreeViews
  .filter((view) => view.level === 5)
  .map((view) => ({
    parent: view,
    children: findGrandchildren(arrayTreeViews, view),
  }));
```

**Original Answer**:

I would use a recursive function here:

```js
const getRelation = (
  tree: Treeview[],
  lowerLevelBound: number,
  level: number,
  fatherId?: number
) => {
  // Find nodes with the given level
  const currentLevelNodes = tree.filter(
    (node) =>
      node.level === level &&
      // If fatherId is not null, filter nodes with wanted father_id
      (fatherId == null ? true : node.father_id === fatherId)
  );

  // We hit the lower level bound -- exit algorithm
  if (level === lowerLevelBound) return currentLevelNodes;

  return currentLevelNodes.map((node) => ({
    parent: node,
    children: getRelation(tree, lowerLevelBound, level - 1, node.id),
  }));
};

const lowerLevelBound = 3;
const upperLevelBound = 5;

const families = getRelation(arrayTreeViews, lowerLevelBound, upperLevelBound);
```

It works by filtering only nodes with level 5 and then recursively mapping them to parent-children relation

Comment: thx a lot for the intermediate solution !!! but now how could I get automatically the relation between `level 5` to `level 3` ? I need to go throught the `level 4` to get the relation but in reality I don't want it ^^ 
I also update my code to match with the data. Nice catch !

Comment: I just edit my initial question with an answer. Do you think what I did is the most efficient way ? Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: @magento2-users It doesn't make sense to always use the most efficient way. Unless it is a really big tree and it needs to be executed often, using `map`s and `filter`s will be much more readable and efficient enough

Comment: I'm asking because it is a really big tree ^^